# Upload an image from a canva javascript to an SVG

Tags: javascript, function, svg, canvas, canvg

[Here's the beginning of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foKFk.png)I made some plots in a javascript canvas and I would like to be able to download them in svg format directly to my computer's hard drive. So I made a button, and a function in javascript, however I must have made a mistake, because when I click nothing happens.

I've test with a javascript function:

```
        function downloadSVG() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("mon-canvas");
        var svg = document.createElement("div");
        svg.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
        svg.setAttribute("width", canvas.width);
        svg.setAttribute("height", canvas.height);

        var dessin = document.getElementById("mon-dessin").innerHTML;
        svg.innerHTML = '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">' +
            dessin +
            '</div></foreignObject>';

        canvg(canvas, svg.innerHTML, {
            ignoreMouse: true,
            ignoreAnimation: true,
            ignoreDimensions: true,
            scaleWidth: canvas.width,
            scaleHeight: canvas.height,
            renderCallback: function() {
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.download = "mon-dessin.svg";
                link.href = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svg.innerHTML);
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            },
        });
    }

</script> 

<button id="telechargerSVG" onclick="downloadSVG()">Télécharger en SVG</button>
```

Comment: a foreignObject element cannot be the child of a div element. Seems like you want an svg element rather than a div.

Comment: Please add a visible code example to clarify what's inside "#mon-dessin" (canvas or svg?)

Comment: Its done, i take a screenshot, if you want to see

Comment: Okay ! Its that i want an svg element, i try lot of thing but i think i've lot of mistakes too...

Comment: I don't know the JavaScript library that you use but you added the URL to the Git repo -- that is not a JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

Miscellaneous observations:

**1.** Attributes only accept strings so...

```
svg.setAttribute("width", canvas.width.toString());
```

**2.** Good luck with...

```
<foreignObject>
```

I've never been able to get that to work with anything serious.

**3.** Totally unnecessary, you don't need these:

```
document.body.appendChild(link);

document.body.removeChild(link);
```

**4.** I would change...

```
link.href = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+btoa(svg.innerHTML);
```

To this...

```
link.href = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg.innerHTML)));
```

Good luck with everything.